# %in% resulting in null output

Tags: r, merge

dataset 1

```
location
Bhilai, C.G
Delhi
Dadar, Mumbai
Bangalore, India
```

dataset 2

```
location  state
Bhilai    C.G
Delhi     Delhi
Dadar     Maharastra
Bangalore Karnataka
```

I want an output like this

output

```
location                 state
Bhilai, C.G              C.G
Delhi                    Delhi
Dadar, Mumbai            Maharashtra
Bangalore, India         Karnatak
```

a

Used code:

```
>    loc$key = 1
>    location2$key = 1
>    newdataset <- merge(loc, location2, by="key")
>    newdataset <- newdataset[newdataset$location.y %in% newdataset$location.x,
         c("location.x", "state")]
```

output:

```
[1] location.x state.y   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: try `dataset1$state <- dataset2$state[match(sub(',.*', '', dataset1$location), dataset2$location)]`

Comment: You are trying to use merge on rows as keys, that will not work. By inserting a column where everything is 1 it makes your key non-distinct. In this case, all you have to do is `cbind(dataset1, dataset2$state)` and you will have the structure you show in this example.

Comment: dataset1$state <- dataset2$state[match(sub(',.*', '', dataset1$location), dataset2$location)]. Tried this still the propblem is same any other solution.Please help.

Comment: cbind() cannot be used, doesn't give resulting output.